# Is AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance protected by SSH Key secure enough?

Tags: security, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance protected by SSH Key. I was thinking, it is secure enough, but I have received an email from Amazon, telling what my instance has been hacked and used for port scanning.

I do not have a reason not to believe Amazon security team, but I do not understand how it is possible. I only use SSH Key to login to the instance, the Key has not been exposed to the world, it only being used from my home computer.

Is there are some security holes in Ubuntu I do not aware of? Is SSH Key is secure enough?

The Instance uses default 64-bit Ubuntu image, provided by AWS. It does not host any web pages.

Comment: Is your instance running any services other than `ssh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default ubuntu image only allows login using SSH keys and prohibits password based logins. Unless you have changed this configuration, it is very unlikely someone got in through SSH.

While unknown vulnerabilities in Ubuntu most certainly exist, their value is very high and it is extremely unlikely that someone will waste potentially millions of dollars worth of vulnerabilities to take over your particular server.

The most likely explanation is that you are running some piece of software (most likely a web application) which is vulnerable and were compromised through it.